# How can I differentiate an android Activity from a SubActivity programatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I differentiate an android Activity from a SubActivity programmatically?
Is there any API for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to detecting whether an activity was started via `startActivityForResult()` or not.

In that case, try `getCallingActivity()`. To quote the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity()), "Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it did not use the `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` form that includes a request code), then the calling package will be null."